# MS SQL Stored procedure to get the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
Staff table:

EmpId   CandidateId
------------------------
  1          2


Candidate table:

CandidateId    Firstname    Last name    CountryId   PassportCountry
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     1           Mark        Antony          2            3           
     2           Joy         terry           1            3

Country:

CountryId      Name
---------------------------
    1           USA
    2           UK
    3           Australia
```

User will pass the `EmpId` in the querystring I need to show the candidate details according to the `empId`. I have only one `country` table and using that table for `country`, passportport country. So I need to get the `country name` when I get the candidate value.

How to write the stored procedure to get the candidate details. Im not good in sql. Can you guys help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Hi I tried the below script to get the country name and passport country name. I can get the country name, but not the passport country.

```
SELECT 
FirstName,
LastName,
PassportCountry,
Country.CountryName as Country
from Candidate 
inner join Country
on country.CountryId=candidate.country
where CandidateId=@CandidateId;
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: What SQL have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: Hi I tried the below script to get the country name and passport country name. I can get the country name, but not the passport country.

Comment: Answer below.  One thing I notice, your `Staff` table is not used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction.

Basically, since you're referencing the Country table twice, you need to join it twice.

```
declare @staff table (EmpId int, CandidateId int)
insert into @staff values (1, 2 )

declare @Candidate table (CandidateId int, Firstname nvarchar(50), Lastname nvarchar(50), CountryId int, PassportCountry int)
insert into @Candidate
values (1, 'Mark', 'Antony', 2, 3),
       (2, 'Joy', 'Terry', 1, 3)

declare @Country table (CountryId int, Name nvarchar(50))
insert into @Country 
values (1, 'USA'),
       (2, 'UK'),
       (3, 'Australia')


declare @empID int
set @empID = 1

SELECT 
FirstName,
LastName,
t2.Name as PersonCountry,
t3.Name as PassportCountry
from @staff s
inner join @Candidate t1 on s.CandidateId = t1.CandidateId
inner join @Country t2 on t1.CountryId=t2.CountryId
inner join @Country t3 on t1.PassportCountry=t3.CountryId
where s.EmpId=@empID;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help Its working fine. User will pass the EmpId in the querystring I need to show the candidate details according to the EmpId. Can you please help me for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated to use `empID`.